# Watir 6 and file upload with Chrome

Tags: selenium, watir

Our UI is made with Vaadin 6. Before upgrade to Watir 6 Chrome file upload automation works like this.

```
$browser.form(:class => "v-upload v-upload-immediate").wait_until_present
$browser.form(:class => "v-upload v-upload-immediate").file_field.set($file_path)
```

Any ideas what has been changed in Watir 6 ( or is it Selenium 3 problem )

Comment: Well I found solution from https://github.com/watir/watir/issues/497

Comment: $browser.form(:class => "v-upload v-upload-immediate").file_field.wait_until(&:exists?).wd.send_keys(File.expand_path($file_path)))